# spring boot not launching static web content

Tags: spring-boot

Am trying to launch index.html in my spring boot app but see 404. What dependency am I missing?

build.gradle (multi project)

```
project('sub-project')
{
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
compile (
    "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.0.0.RC5",
    "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:1.0.0.RC5"
.. few more app specific dependencies
)
```

project structure:

```
MainProject
  -- sub-project
     src
       main
          resources
             index.html
```

Application class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run([SpringServlet, Application, "classpath:/META-INF/com/my/package/bootstrap.xml"] as Object[], args)
    }
}

**Launching http://localhost:8080/index.html throws 404.**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the root cause. Changing the SpringServlet's Url mappings to "Rest" resources specific path fixed it.
Earlier "/*" was also interpreted by SpringServlet and was not able to render the index.html.

```
class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run([Application, "classpath:/META-INF/com/my/package/mgmt/bootstrap.xml"] as Object[], args)
    }

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application);
    }

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new SpringServlet(), "/rest/*");
        Map<String, String> params = ["com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages": "com.my.package.mgmt.impl;com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing"]
        registration.setInitParameters(params)
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    ServletRegistrationBean jerseyJaxrsConfig() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new DefaultJaxrsConfig(), "/api/*");
        Map<String, String> params = ["swagger.api.basepath": "http://localhost:8080/api", "api.version": "0.1.0"]
        registration.setInitParameters(params)
        return registration;
    }
```

Comment: makes sense, deleting my answer and upvoting yours

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

/** do not interpret .123 extension as a lotus spreadsheet */
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) 
    {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

/**
  ./resources/public is not working without this
*/
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/");
}
```

}